# React launching email app from a link problem

Tags: reactjs

I'm coding a React app and I need to understand how can I link the user that clicks the **contact** button to his email web app with the To box automatically filled with the support email.

I mean to go from clicking [this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl633.png)
to this [in the email app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjIdy.png) with the To box automatically filled with the support email

How can I do this in React?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make html link like this: `<a href="mailto:yourmail@example.com" target="_blank">Link</a>`

Answer (score 0):

`mailto:to@gmail.com` in the href of the a tag